# Magento 2 static cache

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

When I would change something in template, I need flush static cache(pub/static) because I didn't saw any changes in front end, but after that this folders has some empty folder and in front end I have some error `ReferenceError: require is not defined` and I need use this command `c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f d:\projects\localsites\magento2.local\magento\bin\magento -- setup:static-content:deploy` to generate static content. Maybe I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you developing something for magento2 you should enable [developer mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html#mode-developer) and static willn't has cache and will generation all requests.

[More about Magento 2 mods you can read on this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html).

Comment: I enable developer mode before.

Comment: Did you change any options in admin about html/css/js?

Comment: No, I just set custom theme and setting fallback, that all. I have always flush static cache when do something with template or css/js

Comment: No. Always after flash static cache, folders pub/static is empty

Comment: 3in developer mode static folder always will empty, but you shouldn't get any errors and css/js should work fine, question about errors and not about empty folder or not

Comment: I installed magento 2 at ubuntu and all problems are gone. Maybe xampp on Windows doesn't has some library or something else